# How do I use PHP with SSL

Tags: php, ssl

My server provides SSL connections via https, although the certificate costs extra...

Is there anything that needs to be changed in the PHP code to utilize this protocol?

My site has:

- ajax forms via POST
- regular forms and pages using POST and GET parameters
- Session variables

Comment: no you dont need to change your code

Comment: Make sure that COOKIES are sent secured.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be good to go. PHP does not impact the use of SSL or not.

Things you should check are:

- Are all URLS in you application relative (no `http://`)
- Are assets (CSS/JS/IMG) used in your site (***both from internal*** and external sources) also as relative paths or prefixed with `https://`

Having an asset without `https://` in a SSL powered site, the browsers will warn you visitors that something ain't right.

Comment: My site at https://presentationtube.com is full of not SSL links, JS, images, etc. but I see no warning messages from chrome. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

you can use the server .htaccess file to redirect all your links. So when the standard page is opened via say a link the server redirects to the https version...

```
# Permanent reirect ALL old pages to HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 2):

Other than any hard-coded URLs, no, your code shouldn't know about the difference, nor care.

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to say the same as mvbrakel, but as far as session cookies/cookies you will want to turn on HTTPS only if you are using https on **ALL** your pages.

Also adding HTTP only to cookies, js scripts won't be able to check value and such.

Answer (score 1):

The code does not need to be changed, other than to change all links from `http://` to `https://` (seriously, don't forget that, else you aren't using SSL...)